# Call action from view to and save the sent value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a two buttons one with a value of true and the other with a value of false;

What I want, is on click to access a method in my application_controller (because here I have it at the moment) which is saving (in redis) the value of the click button, and navigate to the same page(but not with refresh because I'm using turbolinks and I don't want to load everything again).

How can I do something like this, I can probably create a action and make a `post request` with the `value` of the button and then use turbolinks to visit a location. But is this the best way, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you are using Rails built in unobtrusive javascript driver you can create a button, link or form which asynchronously sends data by adding the `remote:true` option.

```
<%= button_to "Do Something", do_some_thing_path, id: 'do_something' remote: true %>
```

This requires that you have:

- an actual route which the button (link or form) can GET, POST, PATCH etc to
- a controller action linked to the route.

You can then listen for events with:

```
jQuery(function(){
  $('#do_something').on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr){
    // @todo handle success.
  }).on('ajax:failure', function(e, data, status, xhr){
    // @todo handle failure.
  });
});
```

I recommend that you read the Rails Guides [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) article for more info.